# Reorder a list with one list comprehension and two conditions

Tags: python, list-comprehension

As it says on the tin. Let's suppose I have a list of strings:
fruits = ['blueberries', 'apricot', 'apple', 'avocado', 'banana', 'apricot','blackberries']

Let's suppose I wanted to reorder this, with fruits starting with 'a' first, then all the 'b' fruits - not in alphabetical order, but in the order they appear in the list. So apricot would the first item in the reordered list. Blueberries would come before banana, etc.

This is trivial with two list comprehensions, even just:

```
fruits = ['blueberries', 'apricot', 'apple', 'avocado', 'banana', 'apricot','blackberries']
    
a_fruit = [x for x in fruits if x[0] == 'a']
b_fruit = [x for x in fruits if x[0] == 'b']
    
print(a_fruit + b_fruit)

['apricot', 'apple', 'avocado', 'apricot', 'blueberries', 'banana', 'blackberries']
```

Is there a way to do this with -one- list comprehension? I don't think if-else works since that only goes through the list once. I assume it would have to be some sort of nested list comprehension that goes through the list twice, first adding the 'a' items then the 'b' items, but I haven't been able to figure it out, and thought I'd double-check that what I'm trying to do isn't impossible.

Even if it is possible - would it be preferable? Seems like the code would get rather hard to read...

EDIT: I should clarify that I'm looking for a general solution that could be used with any two conditions - so I'd like to avoid 'sort' since a general condition might not use strings etc.

Comment: `[x for x in fruits if x[0] in ("a", "b")]` is this what you mean?

Comment: Why does the potential for something other than strings rule out sort?  Sorting doesn't only apply to strings.  It applies to anything which is orderable, which is a necessary condition for the problem anyway.

Answer (score 6):

The best solution here isn't a listcomp, it's sorting. Just do:

```
sorted_fruit = sorted(fruits, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

and it'll put the `a`s before the `b`s while otherwise maintaining the existing order.

If you really insist on a listcomp, you could do a nested loop structure a la:

```
sorted_fruit = [x for prefix in 'ab' for x in fruits if x[0] == prefix]
```

That just loops over `fruits` once for each prefix, so it's doing all the work of the two listcomps in a single listcomp; it's a slight improvement over concatenating the results of two listcomps in terms of performance (since it builds the final `list` directly, not two temporary `list`s that are thrown away to build a third `list`), but it's uglier to my mind.

It's theoretically faster than sorting (it's two `O(n)` operations, rather than one `O(n log n)` operation) but it may be slower in practice (given `sorted` is a built-in implemented in C, and the sort operation is pretty simple), unless the inputs get really huge.

Answer (score 4):

I would say the most *elegant* way of doing this would be to just sort the list based on the first character:

```
>>> sorted(fruits, key=lambda fruit: fruit[0])
['apricot', 'apple', 'avocado', 'apricot', 'blueberries', 'banana', 'blackberries']
```

Alternatively, you can nest the comprehension like this:

```
>>> [f for c in 'ab' for f in fruits if f[0] == c]
['apricot', 'apple', 'avocado', 'apricot', 'blueberries', 'banana', 'blackberries']
```

Comment: But that's not a list comprehension

Comment: ...and I expect the OP will call that two list comprehensions

Comment: Given the statement `Even if it is possible - would it be preferable?` I'd say this answer is fantastic for the question. The answer is essentially no its not preferable, use `sort()`

Comment: My assumption is that it's a challenge from a teacher

Comment: @Steve: The nested listcomp is not two list comps. The OP even mentions trying to figure out how to make a single nested listcomp go through the inputs twice and not figuring it out; this is *how* you'd have it traverse the input twice. It's a perfectly reasonable solution (I'm of course entirely unbiased despite us both independently writing almost identical answers :-) ; juanpa beat me to posting the `sorted` solution, I beat him to the nested listcomp, but I'm fairly sure we both wrote them independently).

Comment: @ShadowRanger - Ah yes, you're right...he mentions a nested comprehension, so I guess that would satisfy his "single comprehension" requirement.  BTW, I'm not critiquing any of the answers at all in terms of solving a particular problem.  I was just reading the question, and wondering it had yet been answered.  Maybe so with the embedded comprehensions.

Comment: @ShadowRanger - and now he's changed his tune (the question), and so your sort method is great!  Did you know going in that `sorted` was stable? - I had to look it up

Comment: @Steve: Yes; Python has one sort to rule them all, and to ensure it's broadly applicable, they guaranteed sort stability (that guarantee has been in place since Python 2.3, when they introduced TimSort). That's why you use a `key` function to narrow the sort criteria to the first character, to avoid comparing second and subsequent characters and performing a full sort that would lose the original ordering (even if it did adequately separate `a` words from `b` words).

Comment: @Steve yes, it's a language guarantee, actually, so it *should* be stable in every implementation